# How to access data of my own non-business Instagram account?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I'm looking for the right approach to solve the following problem:
For my own non-business Instagram account I like to read which accounts follow me and which accounts like and comment my posts.

I read about the old and the new API, about API deprecation etc. Now I'm unsure **which approach shall I choose?**

- Instagram Platform API
- Graph API
- other approach like browser automation (e.g. [InstaPy](https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy))

Instagram/Facebook says "If you are building apps for Instagram Non-Business Accounts, please use the Instagram Platform API". But the process to get an account seams to be complicated. And as I understand until 2020 Instagram will deprecate this API completely.
Additionally as I understand the sandbox mode doesn't help me, since it is [restricted](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/) and won't show the real results.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you should use the Instagram Platform API. I think you're right that the Graph API is only for servicing Business Accounts.

I'm in the same boat. I made an app that lets users sign in with their own non-business accounts. Setup OAuth flow using the old API, which works in sandbox.

However, I submitted for approval this week and haven't heard anything. There's no way to contact Instagram or know how long it will take to get approved.

Answer (score 0):

I personally have some experience with **InstaPy** and I can tell you that it is used mainly for directly interacting with said accounts. You can follow, comment, like, etc... on these accounts that follow you but actually accessing a list of all of them would be more tricky. That's why I ****wouldn't recommend** browser automation** for the goal you have set out for.